# How can I install a desktop 3.5" SATA drive on a laptop without any adapters and use it as the main(system) drive?

Tags: hard-drive, sata

I am pretty sure I'm the first human in the whole universe and multiverses. Here it is...
like an idiot I bought a 3.5" SATA drive for my laptop. I used it to install the OS through USB but I got the "Blue screen of death" when computer restart to finish the installation (XP). 
I am not sure if the size of the disk is the problem or is it because I tried to install through USB. I just bought a SATA cable. to connect the HDD to my laptop through SATA but before a receive the pakage I'd like to know if I'll still have the same problem (Blue Screen Of Death) and if so how can I solve it!!??

My laptop is no longer a laptop, but a desktop since I removed the LCD screen (even the battery actually, and the WiFi :D ). So it won't bother me a bit to have a computer with a mutated HDD.

yeah I know I'm a complete idiot. I only looked at the disk space and the price and I didn't careless about the size. :(

thank you.

Comment: The fact is that there is no way it can possibly fit in your laptop. You might be able to use some convoluted workaround but you'll be wasting time/money and losing portability when you could just return or sell the 3.5" drive and buy a 2.5" one.

Comment: @James my laptop is already a desktop for a longtime now I even removed the screen and I already used it (when I tried the install). I don't thing it will be correct to return it. I might be able to sell it back (even with a higher price ;) ) but we ought to know if it's going to work or not.

Comment: @CarlB Good Game I didn't see that one ;)

Answer (score 2):

One thing to considerate is the current to feed the device. 3.5" uses more power to spin up and revolve the disk. Even if you could feed it with enough power without any external source, probably it won't fit anywhere on a notebook.

I reccomend you to use an [External 3.5" case](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001PHLMAE) with e-Sata interface (assuming that your notebook have a e-Sata entrance). With e-sata you can use your disk just as if it is connected to a normal Sata port:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> How can I install a desktop 3.5" SATA drive on a laptop without any adaptors and use it as the main (system)drive?

Effectivly, your laptop would now be a desk top as mobility would be problamatic for the hard drive, even if you did a butt ungly duck tape job to secure it to the case. But you would need SATA extention of power and a SATA cable.

[image: SATA cable]
[image: SATA power extention]

Easily found with a search on the web.

Also, there is a creative cardboard and duct tape HDD coozy that will offer near zero protection

[image: duct tape]
You could tape the drive it down to the desk so if you forget, you at least wonlt pull the drive to the floor as you move your laptop/desktop.

Once you hook up, reinstall the OS.

Advice as others have stated, but you did not ask for: Return, keep (and install in a 3.5" external enclosure for back ups) or sell the 3.5" and get the proper size drive.

Comment: You both guys are really creative (pics upload ;) ) I won't vote yet until I got my package which by the way is exactly what you advices me to buy. I won't resell or return the disk because I NEED to know if this is going to work... someone need to do it!

P.S my laptop is already a desktop for a longtime now (I even removed the screen)

Comment: That might be a good tib bit of info to put in your question. Being a desk top now more than a laptop.

Comment: It's duck tape.

Comment: @CarlB just done it.

Answer (score 0):

Your Blue Screen of Death was caused by XP doesn't have the correct USB driver.  You need to download something like nLite to slip stream a new version of XP with the correct driver (possibly from drivers pack, do some research on it).

Answer (score 0):

XP (and Windows in general), does not like booting off USB devices.

- If you have eSATA on the laptop, use that along with a power adapter (doubtful as this sounds like an old laptop you're trying to string along)
- Your laptop may even be old enough that it's running an IDE drive - in that case, you'll probably need an IDE cable long enough to snake out of the chassis, an IDE to SATA adapter, and depending on the IDE to SATA adapter, a 2.5" to 3.5" adapter.  I'm pretty sure you'll still need an external power adapter as desktop drives require more power than laptop drives.
- If your laptop has sata on the inside, 2.5" to 3.5" adapter and a cable will be needed, along with the power adapter.

I'll point out, that you'll probably have a hard time finding the appropriate adapters.  While it's relatively common to have adapters for 2.5" drives to fit in 3.5" bays (especially with the prevalence of SSD drives today), going the other way is a bit unusual.  I'm not saying the adapters don't exist, but it'll probably take some looking.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the smps from an old pc to power the hdd and connect the hdd using a sata female to male cable. I am currently working on it and hopefully it works.

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for awnser to the same problem and found none.
So... I sort it out for myself.

1. I split the sata connector in 2 pieces
2. I connected only the data connector to the 3,5 hard disk
3. I used a voltage regulator that draw 20 volts from power in and step down to 12 that I connected to the molex on the hdd
4. I connected the 5 volts on the usb conennector to the same molex

And it worked

Answer (score -1):

I tried to do this to install win 7 on a 3.5 drive in order to be able to put it on a SD card with WinToUSB. Seems not to necessary for that purpose though :)
You need a power supply from an old desktop (cheapest and easiest) and a male to female SATA cable. If the power supply is from a really old pc get a IDE to SATA power converter. That is from 4pin power to the flat SATA connector. 
These cable converters are on ebay for practically no cost.